# Writing an Exodus II file programmatically

Tags: data-visualization, paraview

I want to write an Exodus II (.ex2) file to create a visualization with moving objects in ParaView, something similar to the "can.ex2" example included with the ParaView distribution.

Can anyone show how to do this programmatically? C/C++ preferrably.

Answer (score 0):

To write Exodus II files you should use the Exodus II library. (ParaView uses this library to read/write Exodus II files). The Exodus II library is document (with links to the source) here: https://gsjaardema.github.io/seacas/html/index.html.

Note that the Exodus II library is part of a larger library of tools (named SEACAS). However, it is possible to get the Exodus II library independent of the other utilities as described here: https://github.com/gsjaardema/seacas#exodus.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. My question is more specific though, as I want to know what data I must put into the Exodus-II file to get something similar to the "can.ex2" example. I want to use Exodus-II and ParaView for visualizing the discrete element simulation I wrote in C++.

Comment: SEACAS documentation https://sandialabs.github.io/seacas-docs/sphinx/html/index.html#exodus-library points to https://sandialabs.github.io/seacas-docs/html/index.html; but also check NetCDF? https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-c/current/index.html (Obviously I ended up here looking for something related; IMO documentation lacks KISS-type introduction.