# Export to Exodus file programmatically similar to can.ex2 example in Paraview

Tags: data-visualization, paraview, data-export

I have a similar question to [Writing an Exodus II file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60224064). The linked question has still no accepted answer.

I am performing numerical simulations in MATLAB. My output consists of polyhedra in 3d space and I know the displacement for every vertex in terms of a displacement vector for a finite number of time steps. I would like to visualize the displacement as an animation in Paraview. On YouTube I found a tutorial on animations for the `can.ex2` example in Paraview.

Therefore, I would like to export my data (i.e. initial vertex positions + displacement for each time step) to Exodus 2 format or similar. If possible, I would like to avoid any existing library and write the file myself in MATLAB. I was already successful with *.vtk/.vti/.obj/...* writers for other parts of my project.

Can someone recommend a comprehensive description on how the `.ex2` files should be written and/or code that I can orientate myself on? Unfortunately, I was not very successful with my own research. I am also open for suggestions of similar file formats that would be sufficient for my plans.

Edit
Because I was asked for a code example:

```
% Vertices of unit triangle contained in (x,y)-plane
initialVertexPos = [0, 1, 0;
                    0, 0, 1;
                    0, 0, 0];
nVertices = size(initialVertexPos, 2);

% Linear displacement of all vertices along z-axis
nTimeSteps = 10;    
disp_x = zeros(nTimeSteps, nVertices);
disp_y = zeros(nTimeSteps, nVertices);
disp_z = repmat(linspace(0,1,nTimeSteps)', 1, nVertices); 

% Position of vertex kVertex at time step kTime is given by
% initialVertexPos(:,kVertex) + [disp_x(kTime,kVertex); disp_y(kTime,kVertex); disp_z(kTime,kVertex)]
```

Comment: If you want to write it by yourself, this is not a ParaView - related question. 

That said, If you just want to do some animation in PV, you don't need exodus. You can write one vtk (or vtu or whatever) file per timesteps, and load them as a [file series](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/dataIngestion.html)

Comment: I agree with your suggestion to write one vtk per time step. This is also the way it is implemented right now.
However, I would highly prefer to have just a single output file and my research showed that this is possible with exodus

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.